# Procedure or function 'System_Set_Cookies' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm getting this error when I'm executing my stored procedure:

Procedure or function 'System_Set_Cookies' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied.

But as you can see I already declared @name and it also have a value of integer.

```
**-- Executing my SP**
DECLARE @name int, @Id int, @value nvarchar(255), @update bit;
SET @name = 0;
SET @Id = 0;
SET @value = 'Development';
SET @update = 0;
EXEC System_Set_Cookies;    

**-- Stored Procedure Query**
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[System_Set_Cookies]
            -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
            @name INT,
            @Id INT,
            @value NVARCHAR(255),
            @update BIT
        AS
        BEGIN
            -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
            -- interfering with SELECT statements.
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            -- Insert statements for procedure here
            IF @update = 1
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @Id = COOKIE_ID FROM tbl_Cookies WHERE cookie_name = @name;

                    UPDATE tbl_Cookies SET cookie_name = @name WHERE COOKIE_ID = @Id;

                    UPDATE tbl_Cookies_User SET cookie_value = @value WHERE cookie_id = @Id;
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO tbl_Cookies (cookie_name) VALUES (@name);

                    SELECT @Id = MAX(COOKIE_ID) FROM tbl_Cookies;

                    INSERT INTO tbl_Cookies_User (cookie_id, cookie_value) VALUES (@Id, @value);
                END
        END
```

Comment: Also tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: @YogeshSharma sorry but I need to run it also through C# and I'm getting the same error there, so I think your answer will not be possible. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: @YogeshSharma MS SQL

Comment: _"I'm getting this error when I'm executing my stored procedure:"_ Where are you executing it? How? Post the code that executes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have a variable who's name matches a stored procedure's parameter name, SQL Server doesn't assume that you necessarily want to pass that variable as a parameter. You have to be explicit:

```
DECLARE @name int, @Id int, @value nvarchar(255), @update bit;
SET @name = 0;
SET @Id = 0;
SET @value = 'Development';
SET @update = 0;
EXEC System_Set_Cookies @name, @id, @value, @update;
```

And the names don't even have to match:

```
DECLARE @OOname int, @Id int, @value nvarchar(255), @update bit;
SET @OOname = 0;
SET @Id = 0;
SET @value = 'Development';
SET @update = 0;
EXEC System_Set_Cookies @name = @OOname, @id, @value, @update;
```

(When calling from C#, make sure you set the `CommandText` to just the name of the stored procedure and the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` and then the parameters are automatically matched up without having to be explicit there)